# Use Web Api in a MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I must create a Web service and application that will use my web service.

I created Web Api project and I have there this method:

```
namespace StudentListApi.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        StudentContext db = new StudentContext();
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return db.Students;
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

I need to use this method in controller. My MVC site takes data of students. And takes this data in view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private const string APP_PATH = "http://localhost:2640";

    private Models.StudentListEntities db = new Models.StudentListEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        //var students = db.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var students = client.GetAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/value").Result;
            //return students.StatusCode.ToString();
            return View(students);
        }

    }
}
```

But is doesn't work and I have an error:

[image]

The error is in Russian, but I think you can understand from name of exception and that type of item model must be `StudentList.Model.Student` but i have HttpResponseMessage.

How I can take data from Web Service, transform it in the type `"StudentList.Model.Student"` and give it to `View()`?

Comment: What do you have in `Result`? Is it a JSON string, XML? What does your API return?

Comment: Im noob, and I dont know what API returns and i dont know how I can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mentioned URL is in string. I think you need to use URI based address.

Also, alongwith GetAsync you need to use async and await keywords.

Try below sample-

```
public class DataSourceController : Controller
{
    HttpClient _client;
    string webapiurl = "http://localhost:56472/api/DataSource";

    public DataSourceController()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webapiurl);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
    }


    //
    // GET: /DataSource/
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var ResponseMessage = await _client.GetAsync(webapiurl);

        if(ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            var data = ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var datasource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataSourceInfo>>(data);
            return View(datasource);

        }

        return View("Error");

    }
}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: See updated code...
Hope you are using these 3 namespaces-
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: IT WORKS! BIG THANK YOU                                                                                but I a bit edited code because was errors                                                       [workcode](http://imgur.com/uMDePu5)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a webservice call, you will need to deserialize the response from the call.
 
Kind of Deserialization will be based on the response you have configured in the Api.

And it needs to be done on `Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` value.

Comment: Okay, and im taking it to View() ? And how I can use this in view?                         For example that I have now                                                                               model IEnumerable < StudentList.Models.Student >                                          foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>item.Name</td>
            <td>item.Surname</td>

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = client.GetAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/value").Result.Content;
                var students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Student>>(content);
                return View(students);
            }
        }

Here I'm assuming that content is in Json Format from Api. 
If it is Xml Format, you need to do XML Deserialization.
NB: You get 'JsonConvert' type from the NewtonSoft Nuget Package.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     var students = client.GetAsync(APP_PATH + "/api/value").Result;
     //return students.StatusCode.ToString();
     return View(students);
}
```

your path like that (APP_PATH + "/api/value") but your controller name "**Values**Controller" edit your **ValuesController** to **ValueController** or change your path like that (APP_PATH + "/api/values")

Then check your api ("`http://localhost:2640/api/values`") works fine than check your request code in HomeController.

I worked it in console application and use Newtonsoft nuget package

> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("yourRootUrl");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        var res = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            data.Wait();
            return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(data.Result);
        });
        res.Wait();
        foreach (var s in res.Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes in browser it works fine, but in HomeController it doesn't work. In Google Chrome Im taking xml format, in Internet Explorer im taking json format. Now I know that I must use Deserialize but it doesn't working too. I have errors

Comment: I added sample HttpClient using and deserialize. Don't forget add application/json client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));